# air for android - Cant upload to FTP

Tags: android, upload, air, ftp, adobe

I'm trying to upload a simple text file to ftp, the code works on the pc.
On android the app connects successfully to the ftp but when I try to upload the file I get "2031:Error #2031: Socket Error."
Any ideas?

The code (from http://suzhiyam.wordpress.com/2011/04/) is:

import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

import flash.events.Event;

import flash.net.Socket;

import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

import flash.errors.IOError;

import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

import flash.filesystem.File;

import flash.utils.ByteArray;

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

msg.text="Wait! Connecting to ftp server!"

//

var ftp_host:String = "*****";     //FTP settings are correct in the original code...

var ftp_port:Number = 21;

var ftp_username:String = "*****";

var ftp_password:String = "*****";

//

//in this demo we will be manually entering the remote servers folder from which upload or download should happen

var remoteFolderStr:String;

var localFolderStr:String;

var remoteFile:String;

//Socket instance which will be used to connect to ftp server

var s = new Socket(ftp_host,ftp_port);

s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);

s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onReturnData);

s.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnectHandler);

//

//Socket instance which will be used to connect to receive data sent by ftp server

var r:Socket = new Socket();

r.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onServData);

r.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onPasvConn);

r.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);

//For every command the client sends to ftp server the server returns message with return codes

function onReturnData(evt:ProgressEvent)

{

```
var d = s.readUTFBytes(s.bytesAvailable);

trace(d);

//check here for complete list of return codes and their meaning

//- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes



// the return message will have a 3 digit return code followed by a space and related message

// if the 3 digit return code is followed by "-" the it will be a multiline message

//-wait until the line with 3 digit code followed by space is delivered

if (d.indexOf("220 ") > -1)

{

    msg.text="Logging in to ftp server!"

    //connected to ftp server send user name to server

    s.writeUTFBytes("USER "+ftp_username+"\n");

    s.flush();

}

if (d.indexOf("331 ") > -1)

{

    //Username accepted now send password to server

    s.writeUTFBytes("PASS "+ftp_password+"\n");

    s.flush();

}

if (d.indexOf("230") > -1 && d.indexOf("OK.") > -1)

{

    msg.text="Log in successful!"

    //Password accepted - lets enetr passive mode and retrive a list of files from a directory

    //first enetr passive mode

    //s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");

    //s.flush();



}

var a = d.indexOf('227');

if (a > -1)

{

    //Entering passive mode message will be returned along with it details of ip and port address will be returned

    //-we have to connect to that address to receive the data

    //format of the message will be: 227 Entering Passive Mode (209,190,85,253,148,206)

    //the data inside brackets is the ip and port address, first four numbers represent IP and last 2 PORT

    //the port value have to be calculated by multiplying the 5th number with 256 and adding the 6th number to it

    //here in this example IP is 209.190.85.253 , PORT is (148*256)+206 = 38094

    var st = d.indexOf("(",a);

    var en = d.indexOf(")",a);

    var str;

    str = d.substring(st + 1,en);

    var a2 = str.split(",");

    var p1 = a2.pop();

    var p2 = a2.pop();

    var ip:String = a2.join(".");

    var port:int=(p2*256)+(p1*1);

    r.connect(ip, port);

}

if (d.indexOf("226 ") > -1)

{

    //Data Transfer completed

    //s.writeUTFBytes("QUIT \n");

    //s.flush();

    if (process=='download')

    {

        msg.text="DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"



    }

    if (process=='upload')

    {

        msg.text="UPLOAD_COMPLETE"

    }

    dispatchEvent(new Event("dataReceived"))

}

if (d.indexOf("221 ") > -1)

{

    //LOGGED OUT from server

}

//Response code 150 will be sent by server whenever a data connection is established after we send 'PASV' command

if (d.indexOf("150 ") > -1)

{

    if (process == 'upload')

    {

        //Once data connection is established we can start sending the data to the server

        startSendingData();

    }

}
```

}

function onConnectHandler(evt:Event)

{

```
msg.text="CONNECTED TO FTP SERVER!"

trace("CONNECTED TO FTP SERVER");

//Client has connected to ftp server
```

}

function onPasvConn(evt:Event):void

{

```
trace("CONNECTED TO DATA PORT");



//s.writeUTFBytes("LIST /your/folder/path\n");



if (process=='upload')

{

    //To Upload a file send following command

    //STOR is the command followed by a space and path wher to store the file in remote server

    //-with the name of the file to be saved as..you can provide any name with extension

    s.writeUTFBytes("STOR /test.txt\n");

}

s.flush();
```

}

function onServData(evt:ProgressEvent):void

{

```
//DATA RECEIVED FROM SERVER THRO DATA PORT
```

}

function onIOERR(evt:IOErrorEvent)

{

```
trace(evt.errorID+":"+evt.text);
```

}

//

var process:String = "";// variable to store what action is being performed

var writeToStream:Boolean;//not used here

var localFile:File;//local file which it to be uploaded

var localFolder:File;// local folder to which the downloaded file to be stored

var interval:Number;

var bufferSize:int;

//

BTN_Upload.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,initUpload);

function initUpload(evt:MouseEvent=null):void

{

```
//called when upload event is triggered

startUploadProcess();
```

}

function startUploadProcess():void

{

```
process = "upload";

//You need to pass this command 'TYPE I' to set data transfer mode as binary

s.writeUTFBytes("TYPE I\n");

s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");

s.flush();
```

}

function startSendingData():void

{

```
var textToUpload:String = "This is a test";



bufferSize = textToUpload.length;



var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();



//Store the info you want to upload in ByteArray HERE

ba.writeMultiByte(textToUpload, "iso-8859-1");



r.writeBytes(ba, 0, ba.bytesAvailable);

r.flush();
```

}

Comment: i have the same issue,please help